# How can my @WebMvcTest test classes initialize with this JDBC authentication configuration in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, testing, spring-annotations

I have configured my Spring Boot application to use a local database for authentication, and it works (with one caveat, c.f. [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58597610/how-to-initialize-spring-boot-security-config-with-default-username-password-but)), but not all of my test classes work well with the new configuration.

Here's the relevant part of the configuration (see it all [here](https://github.com/joeclark-phd/granite/blob/master/src/main/java/net/joeclark/webapps/granite/config/WebSecurityConfig.java)):

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
    builder .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .withUser(User.withUsername("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("pass")).roles("SUPER"));
    logger.debug("Configured app to use JDBC authentication with default database.");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

The test classes decorated with `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` work (for example, [this one](https://github.com/joeclark-phd/granite/blob/master/src/test/java/net/joeclark/webapps/granite/home/HomeControllerIntegrationTest.java)).  As I understand it, these ones auto-configure the various Beans of the application and test them together (a form of integration test).

**I'm having trouble with the test classes decorated with `@WebMvcTest`** (such as [this one](https://github.com/joeclark-phd/granite/blob/master/src/test/java/net/joeclark/webapps/granite/home/HomeControllerMVCTest.java)).  These are supposed to test just one Controller class itself, using mock objects for the various Beans and other dependencies.

- Since implementing the configuration above, they first started crashing with an `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` ... "No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available".
- I then added these lines to each such test case:

```
@MockBean
private DataSource dataSource;
```

- The first exception seems to go away, but now I get the following error in my logs:
  `Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection: DataSource returned null from getConnection(): javax.sql.DataSource#0 bean`

These tests use the `@WithMockUser` annotation in a few places and are not expected to use the real database or the JDBC connection, since they're each just testing a single controller.

**My question**: How can I use @WebMvcTest with my current security configuration without the test classes failing?  Is there a convenient Spring Boot annotation I should add to the test class?  Am I doing the security configuration wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that made the tests work was to add this property to my `application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  datasource: 
    initialization-mode: always
```

Or if you prefer to use an `application.properties` config file, it would look like this:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

I give credit to user [Japan Trivedi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/944108/japan-trivedi) who pointed me to this on my related question.